# How to clone Linked List with Kotlin?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, linked-list

I just learn the data structure Linked List.

My question is very simple: **How to clone a Linked List?**

(return head is not clone.)

Here is my try but result is no good.
(ex. input(1,2,3,4,5) output (1,5)

How can I fix it.

```
    class ListNode(var `val`: Int) {
        var next: ListNode? = null
    }
```

```
    fun cloneLiskedList(head: ListNode?): ListNode? {

        if (head == null) {
            return null
        }

        val answer = ListNode(head.`val`)
        var tempListNode: ListNode ?= null
        var headPoint = head.next

        while (headPoint != null) {

            val listNode = ListNode(headPoint.`val`)
            tempListNode = listNode
            tempListNode.next = listNode
            headPoint = headPoint.next
        }

        answer.next = tempListNode

        return answer
    }
```

input(1,2,3,4,5)

output (1,5)//expected (1,2,3,4,5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work

```
fun cloneLiskedList(head: ListNode?): ListNode? {
    if (head == null) {
        return null
    }

    val answer = ListNode(head.`val`)
    var tempListNode: ListNode? = answer
    var headPoint = head.next

    while (headPoint != null) {
        tempListNode?.next = ListNode(headPoint.`val`)
        headPoint = headPoint.next
        tempListNode = tempListNode?.next
    }

    return answer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a simpler way to achieve this all you need to do is
change

```
  class ListNode(var `val`: Int) {
        var next: ListNode? = null
    }
```

to

```
data class ListNode(var `val`: Int , var next: ListNode? = null)
```

then simply call built in `copy` function :

```
val clone = listNode.copy()
```